# Can't pass nil to two optional parameters

Tags: function, swift, null

I'm in the process of converting an Objective-C category to a Swift extension to provide simplified methods for adding constraints. One method for equally spacing views has the following signature,

```
func addAndEquallySpaceViews(views: [UIView], leftOrTopSpace: CGFloat?, rightOrBottomSpace: CGFloat?, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions?)
```

I call it like this,

```
self.view.addAndEquallySpaceViews([view1, view2], leftOrTopSpace: nil, rightOrBottomSpace: nil, options: .AlignAllBottom)
```

I want to be able to pass nil to the leftOrTopSpace and rightOrBottomSpace parameters, but when I pass nil for both of them, I get a series of compile time errors. I can pass nil for either of them alone, but not for both. Why can't I pass nil for both optional parameters?

The errors I'm getting seem to be non-specific, and not related to the line in question,

[image]

Comment: Cool! What a great error. :) And I can reproduce it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the nil CGFloats. It's the implicit enumeration type. Here's your workaround:

```
self.view.addAndEquallySpaceViews([view1, view2], 
    leftOrTopSpace: nil, rightOrBottomSpace: nil, 
    options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllBottom)
```

Comment: So now you can carry on without changing your API and passing the same values you want to pass. But do report this to Apple, please. Crashing the compiler is always unwarranted!

Comment: That's a solution I wouldn't have thought of. Do you have any idea why the implicit enumeration works if I pass one nil but not two?

Comment: Not the slightest idea nor the slightest interest. It's a bug in the compiler. Tell Apple and let them figure it out!